# How addition of 2 recursive function works

Tags: c++

How does the recursive function  return printCountRec(dist-1)  + printCountRec(dist-2); works in following code. By my logic The printCountRec(dist-1) function call will return 1 and printCountRec(dist-2) will return 0 by adding these two ,answer should be 1+0 i.e 1 but I am getting the answer as 3. I am not getting it.

Program for Count number of ways to cover a distance;
The code is as follows-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int printCountRec(int dist)
{
    // Base cases
    if (dist<0)    return 0;
    else if (dist==0)  return 1;

    // Recur for all previous 3 and add the results
   else   return printCountRec(dist-1)  + printCountRec(dist-2);

}

int main()
{
    int dist = 3;
    cout << printCountRec(dist);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with C? This isn't valid C code. And you should learn to use a debugger and step through your code to understand what it is doing

Comment: Sounds like you should step through the code with a debugger. That will show you exactly hoe the program flows.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'm following your recursion:

```
printCountRec(-1) = 0
printCountRec(0) = 1
printCountRec(1) = printCountRec(0) + printCountRec(-1) = 1
printCountRec(2) = printCountRec(1) + printCountRec(0) = 2
printCountRec(3) = printCountRec(2) + printCountRec(1) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

> The printCountRec(dist-1) function call will return 1 and printCountRec(dist-2) will return 0

How did you suppose this? Step by step :

- `printCountRec(dist-1)` means `printCountRec(2)`, which will call `printCountRec(1) + printCountRec(0)`. For these two, the first will call `printCountRec(0) + printCountRec(-1)`, which will return `1+0 = 1` to printCountRec(2), and the second will return `1` to printCountRec(2).

  In other words you have this order :

  ```
  printCountRec(dist-1) = printCountRec(2) -->
  printCountRec(1) + printCountRec(0) -->
  printCountRec(0) + printCountRec(-1) + 1 -->
  1 + 0 + 1 --> 3
  ```

  ***So the first member of the addition is evaluated to `2`.***
- `printCountRec(dist-2)` means `printCountRec(1)`, which will call `printCountRec(0) + printCountRec(-1)` , returning `1+0 = 1` to `printCountRec(1)`.

  In other words you have this order :

  ```
  printCountRec(dist-2) = printCountRec(1) -->
  printCountRec(0) + printCountRec(-1) -->
  1 + 0 --> 1
  ```

  ***So the second member of the addition is evaluated to `1`.***

Adding the two members (`2` and `1`) gives you the result `3`.

Answer (score 0):

dist = -1 outputs 0

dist = 0 outputs 1

dist = 1 outputs 1

dist = 2 outputs 2

dist = 3 outputs 3

printCountRec(2) = printCountRec(1) + printCountRec(0) = 2

printCountRec(3) = printCountRec(2) + printCountRec(1) = 2 + 1 = 3.